# How to Use JQuery to Find All Readonly Text Boxes on a Web Page

Tags: jquery

I have been asked to identify all read only text boxes in an Asp.Net page and assign a particular style.  I'm pretty sure I could iterate over all of the inputs to see if they were  inputs that were text boxes with the readonly attribute but I just KNOW there's a one liner.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$('input[type=text][readonly]')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rZvnm/

Answer (score 6):

Technically, this should be enough to limit to readonly text inputs:

```
$(':text[readonly]'); // equivalent to $('*:text[readonly]')
```

But if it was me I like to be a little more specific and include a tag (jQuery recommends it as well):

```
$('input:text[readonly]');
```

And also according to the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/), it is faster in modern browsers to use the type attribute selector instead of `:text`:

```
$('input[type=text][readonly]');
```

I use `[readonly]` instead of `[readonly=readonly]` to merely test for the presence of the attribute, not what its value is.

Comment: nice, but 'text[readonly]' (and 'input:text[readonly]' or '*:text[readonly]') refuses to work. (however '[type=text][readonly]' works as expected)

Answer (score 4):

```
$.extend($.expr[':'],{
    readonly: function(obj) {
        return $(obj).is('[readonly]');
    }
});

 $('input:text:readonly');
```

it is the best way I found.

Answer (score 2):

try the below

```
$('input[Type="text"]&[readonly="readonly"]')
```